# What are the cases that cause WCF proxy to be faulted?

Tags: c#, wcf, fault-tolerance

I want to know what are the cases in which WCF proxy (generated by vs2008 or svcutil) becomes faulted (fault state)? so I can recreate new instance and avoid use the faulted one.

currently I am handling TimeoutException,FaultException,CommunicationObjectAbortedException

```
            try
            {
                client.Method1(args);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                client.Abort();
                ReCreate();
            }
            catch (FaultException)
            {
                client.Abort();
                ReCreate();
            }
            catch (CommunicationObjectAbortedException)
            {
                client.Abort();
                ReCreate();
            }
```

I think I can avoid all these types and handle only the parent CommunicationException, is this sufficient? I need comments

Answer (score 2):

Any uncaught exception on the server side that isn't handled and converted into a `FaultException` or `FaultException<T>` will likely fault your channel. In a per-call scenario or a one-way scenario, you often don't really care about the channel being faulted, but in a session-based scenario, you definitely will!

Your best bet is to really try and catch all exceptions on the server side and either just suppress them (log them on the server and don't do anything), or return them to the client in a `FaultException` way.

In order to do that, your service implementation should also implement the [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface which allows you to do just that - catch all exceptions and either logging+suppressing them, or converting them to SOAP faults.

Marc

Comment: In case of expected exceptions like (UnauthorizedAccessException or any) that the server throws, it will fault the session and the client should take of that!!

Comment: Yes, there are some cases where you will want to propagate the exception to the client - but that's the exception rather than the rule

Answer (score 0):

WCF proxy object can become faulted because of any sort of exception except a faultException. So basically you best bet is just to check the proxy state and of it is faulted create a new one.

Another thing to keep in mind is that faulted is related to WCF sessions. If you don't need WCF sessions make sure to turn them off and you have prevented a whole series of possible issues.

Comment: "WCF proxy object can become faulted because of any sort of exception except a faultException"
Do you mean the generic FaultException<T> that decorates the service methods?

Comment: for "any sort of exception" does it mean if the service has something like "throw new Exception();" that will fault the session?

Comment: A FaultException<T> derives from and therefor is a FaultException. If the service does a "throw new Exception();" this will fault the proxy if sessions are used.